# How do you update max CPA bids through the Adwords API?

Tags: google-ads-api

I can see how one update target CPA bids through the api however I am wondering if you can update max CPA bids?

Answer (score 0):

You can't as far as I can tell.  Closest option is 'TargetCpa'